# Dealing with "borrowed value does not live long enough" within for loops

Tags: rust, ownership

A site I am scraping requires me to query the title tag of an HTML page as well as a few other elements to see if I can discern the title of the article.

I create a `HashMap<&str, u8>` and immediately `.insert(title_tag_text, 1)`, query for the header elements and then I am hoping to insert the header tags' text into the hash map similarly but I get the error `borrowed value does not live long enough`.

I'm not sure I understand since I thought I was properly dereferencing the `std::string::String` into a `&str` which should implement the `Copy` trait? Unfortunately, I suspect the next code I plan to implement has a similar issue.

```rust
let mut title_candidates: HashMap<&str, u8> = HashMap::new();

let title_tag_text: String = Selector::parse("title")
    .ok()
    .and_then(|selector| html_document.select(&selector).next())
    .map(|elem| elem.inner_html())?;

title_candidates.insert(&*title_tag_text, 1);

Selector::parse("h1, h2, h3, .title")
    .ok()
    .as_ref()
    .map(|selector| html_document.select(selector))?
    .map(|elem| elem.inner_html()) // std::string::String
    .for_each(|title| {
        *title_candidates.entry(&*title).or_insert(0) += 1;
        // if title_tag_text.contains(&*title.as_str()) {
        //     *title_candidates.entry(&*title_tag_text) += 1;
        // }
    });
```

```
error[E0597]: `title` does not live long enough
   --> src/main.rs:140:39
    |
125 |     let mut title_candidates: HashMap<&str, u8> = HashMap::new();
    |         -------------------- lifetime `'1` appears in the type of `title_candidates`
...
140 |             *title_candidates.entry(&*title).or_insert(0) += 1;
    |              -------------------------^^^^^-
    |              |                        |
    |              |                        borrowed value does not live long enough
    |              argument requires that `title` is borrowed for `'1`
...
144 |         });
    |         - `title` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `HashMap`'s keys are of type `&str`. This means that the `HashMap` only holds a *reference* to a `str` and not the `str` itself. Therefore, for the data in the `HashMap` to be valid, the reference to the `str` should live at least as long as the `HashMap`. Now the issue is, the `String` is being created in `.map(|elem| elem.inner_html())` and therefore it gets dropped after that statement is completed.

Instead, create a `HashMap` which uses *owned* `String`s instead of references. Below is a simplified example that you can adapt for your case:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut data: HashMap<String, i32> = HashMap::new();

    (0..20)
        .map(|i| (i % 10).to_string())
        .for_each(|text| {
            *data.entry(text).or_insert(0) += 1;
        });
}
```

Here, `.map(|i| (i % 10).to_string())` creates a `String` whose ownership is then passed to the `HashMap` in `data.entry(text)` thus avoiding any mismatches in the lifetimes of references.

[**Rust Playground**](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5a5a50780fcec5edc4ec040841c8b103)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your case is a very common one which I many times stumbled upon.
Rust does not have a garbage collector this is very well known but often we have a hard time understanding the actual implications of this.

In your case, you are trying to store a reference to a string in your map which exists only that for_each function.

Here comes the question, what happens when that function returns?
When that function returns the objects created in that function will be `free`d and if that string you `&str` points to is freed your `&str` will be pointing at a location that does not belong to you anymore.

If you want to use references you need to make sure that things they refer to survive as long as the reference is in use.

In your case above simply using a owned string will fix the issue which will be owned by the hashmap in this case and will be around as long as the hashmap does.

So you should edit your hashmap signature to `HashMap<String,u8>`
and while inserting simply pass an owned copy of the `&str` using either `.to_string()` or `.to_owned()`